# Driver for SQL server 2012 in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

So I have a java program and am using the following driver

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

to try to read data from a SQL server 2012 database, but I get the

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost....
```

If I have a  SQL server 2012 database, can I not use the com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver driver? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the library (jar) as dependency for your project?

Comment: Are you (by chance) catching and ignoring any exception thrown by the `Class.forName` call?

Comment: Are you receptive to using JTDS instead of the Microsoft Driver?  That is what I would recommend, and what I use.

Comment: @ChrisParker The jTDS driver is severely out of date and hasn't been updated to provide JDBC 4, 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 features that I'm aware of.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Oh crud.  Shows how far out of date I am with M.S. SQL!  In days gone by it was a much better driver.  Not only was it faster, but it had other advantages as well.  Too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing the driver class and you should add that to your project.

Just a [quick search](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc) on the [Maven Central](http://www.mvnrepository.com) produces this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Assuming that you run Java 8 and Maven, you can add this as a dependency to your project.

Comment: I was not using maven and the class path of the jar was not added. I added it and it works..thankyou